# Getting data/output from a shell command in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the output of a shell command into my node cli app. I have been trying so many things but nothing seems to get me the output.

The command I run has steps like:

```
$ particle token list
Checking with the cloud...
? Using account ****@****.com
Please enter your password: [hidden]
? Please enter a login code [optional] 

__PASSWORD_ONLY__ (active)
token: sometoken here //this is what I and trying to get mainly
```

I am running it from my app like

```
const execute = require('child_process').spawnSync;


    const child = execute('particle', ["token", "list"], {encoding: 'utf-8'});
    
    if(child.error) {
        console.log("ERROR: ",child.error);
    }
    console.log("stdout: ",child.stdout);
    console.log("stderr: ",child.stderr);
    console.log("exist code: ",child.status);
```

When I run it I get

```
$ node test.js       
stdout:  ? Using account ****@****.com
Please enter your password: [input is hidden] 
stderr:  Checking with the cloud...

exist code:  255
```

I have tried some other ways found by searching but didn't help much. What can I try so that the command would finish after inputting and returns all the outputs? Help would be much appreciated.

PS: It does not have to be `spawnSync` or any synchronous method, just using it for test purpose.

Comment: why not you use the [js sdk](https://docs.particle.io/reference/SDKs/javascript/#listaccesstokens)?

Comment: I could but I am actually trying to teach myself about some corners and stuff in node.js :)